# Notifications repeated while using the app

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I created notifications that are shown at a specific time that I set in shared preferences.
Notifications work correctly at the set time, however they are also shown when I use the app about every minute.
If I delete them from the navbar after a while the notification is retransmitted.
How can I send the notifications only at the time I set?
I am in Android 8 Api 26

**This is the class that I initialize in the onCreate of the MainActivity so as to set the Alarm Manager**

```
public class NotificationApp {


    private Context CONTEXT;

    public NotificationApp(Context context) {
        this.CONTEXT = context;

    }

    public void SetNotification() {

        SharedPreferencesApp sharedPreferencesApp = new SharedPreferencesApp(CONTEXT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sharedPreferencesApp.getHourPreferences());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sharedPreferencesApp.getMinutesPreferences() - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);


        Intent intentNotificationApp = new Intent(CONTEXT, NotificationApp.Notification_reciver.class);
        intentNotificationApp.setAction("MY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CONTEXT, 0, intentNotificationApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }
```

**In the onCreate() of the MainActivity**
`new NotificationApp(getActivityContext()).SetNotification();`

**Then the class that extends BroadcastReceiver**

```
        public Notification_reciver() {

        }

        @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), "MY_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE")) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent intentGetNotificationExpired = new Intent(context, ArticoliScaduti.class);
                intentGetNotificationExpired.putExtra("today", true);
                intentGetNotificationExpired.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentGetNotificationExpired, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilderExpired = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "dispensa_channel")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("title text")
                        .setContentText("body text")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "some_text", pendingIntent);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notificationChannelOne", "channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    channel.setDescription("name_channel");

                    ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
                    notificationBuilderExpired.setChannelId(channel.getId());
                }

                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilderExpired.build());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! The problem was that to initialize the Service more than once, solved by setting a parameter that set the initialization or not in a shared preferences so that it is initialized only once.